# What is this called in an Object literal?

Tags: javascript

so my question is when using an object literal inside a method I see people doing 'this.something = ...'

And then referencing it throughout their object. What's the name for this?

For e.g. Here in the example below if you look in the 'CacheDom' method 'this.button = document.getElementById('submit')' gives us a reference we can use later.

I understand the basics of the 'this' keyword and inside an object it will reference to that object, but I found it strange to be able to store elements etc and reference them later.

Essentially what is the official term for this?

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/rvs6ymqj/

HTML

```
<body>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
var obj = {
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  cacheDom: function() {
    this.button = document.getElementById('submit');
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    this.button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("we clicked the button");
    })
  }
}

obj.init();
```

Comment: Object Oriented Programming?

Comment: The official term for `this` is "this". Some people say "context", which isn't official or precise. More correct might be "receiver" but that isn't official either. *"but I found it strange to be able to store elements etc and reference them later"* If the value of `this` is an object (which it doesn't have to be) then you are simply assigning properties to an object. That's not different from using `obj` instead of `this`, `obj.foo = 42;` (if `obj` refers to an object).

Comment: Hey, yeah it made sense when you said 'assigning properties to an object'. I think it's because I'm used to always defining my properties using a colon rather than adding them like that.

Thanks!

Comment: `this` is nothing special in an *object literal*. It does gain a meaning when used in an object *method* however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies from language to language. In Javascript, it's called a [property](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp). In Java, they're [fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/field.html). C++ also calls them fields, though they may also be called [data members](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/CppTutorial/NOTES/CLASSES-INTRO.html).

JS is notably different from the other two in that Java and C++ force you to declare your fields, while JS members are defined on the fly. Really, JS objects are just maps from keys to values: the properties are the keys.

Answer (score 1):

In Object-Oriented Programming, "this" refers to the object you are inside. You aren't storing properties in "this". It is a way to differentiate between global variables/constructor parameters and instance variables of the same name. I don't think there's a specific name for the concept of "this" but this phrase sums it up nicely:

> 'this' is usually an immutable reference or pointer which refers to the current object

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming)

Javascript-Specific Explanation:

> JavaScript
>
> When used outside any function, in global space, this refers to the
>   enclosing object, which in this case is the enclosing browser window,
>   the window object. When used in a function defined in the global
>   space, what the keyword this refers to depends on how the function is
>   called. When such a function is called directly (e.g. f(x)), this will
>   refer back to the global space in which the function is defined, and
>   in which other global functions and variables may exist as well (or in
>   strict mode, it is undefined). If a global function containing this is
>   called as part of the event handler of an element in the document
>   object, however, this will refer to the calling HTML element. When a
>   method is called using the new keyword (e.g. var c = new Thing()) then
>   within Thing this refers to the Thing object itself. When a function
>   is attached as a property of an object and called as a method of that
>   object (e.g. obj.f(x)), this will refer to the object that the
>   function is contained within. It is even possible to manually
>   specify this when calling a function, by using the .call() or .apply()
>   methods of the function object. For example, the method call
>   obj.f(x) could also be written as obj.f.call(obj, x). To work around
>   the different meaning of this in nested functions such as DOM event
>   handlers, it is a common idiom in JavaScript to save the this
>   reference of the calling object in a variable (commonly called that or
>   self), and then use the variable to refer to the calling object in
>   nested functions.